# Second display won't work with nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, multiple-monitors

I have recently installed Ubuntu but the drivers from x.org are not so good, because:

- the display with NVidia graphics card (plugged by HDMI) has some problems server x from x.org nouveau driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)
- the second one plugged by DVI to the Intel GPU works just fine.

After driver change to NVidia drivers nvidia binary driver version 470.76 from nvidia-340 (opensource) I noticed that the HDMI display works fine, but the DVI one is just blank and not detected neither by the NVidia x server settings nor the system display settings.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) I'm sorry and, please, blame it on me: I'm confused and confusing...  But...  *What's your question???* :/

Comment: How can i get second monitor to work :)

Comment: If you cant understand something it might be my fault my english is not perfect :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give more information.  Replace **which** by actual problem/driver.  Bad English is no problem;  too little information is a problem!  **;-)**

Comment: Edited with drivers name :)

Answer (score 0):

The standard Ubuntu NVidia drivers generate some problems on slightly older *and* slightly newer NVidia hardware.

If you want *more* then the standard Ubuntu repository drivers, install the [xorg.edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA.  As the xorg.edgers group ask not to give installation instructions directly without linking to their page, this is the best I can do *for now...*

If you don't know what a PPA is or need some guidance about rolling forward and backward of driver versions after reading their page, leave a comment below.

Comment: Do you think that might also be relevant for [my somewhat similar problem](http://askubuntu.com/q/809976/193641)?

Comment: @einpoklum sorry, never even saw kubuntu running...